# Iterate over a string to remove specific characters swift

Tags: swift, string, loops

I have a string which shows a time in hh:mm:ss:ms and I need to iterate over the string and remove unwanted characters to then display in a label.

So for example if the time string was 00:25:30:00 I'd want the final output to be 25:30 or if the string was 00:25:00:30 it needs to output 25:00:30

I have the below code, which I thought worked until I realised I only want to remove characters when there are two zeros next to each other, so not sure how to achieve this. I'm self teaching myself to code, so apologise if this is a typical noob or stupid question...

```
    var gTimeString = "00:25:30:00"
    var gTimeStringReduced = ""

//iterate over string and remove zeros
    for char in gTimeString {
        print("character = \(char)")
        if char != "0" {
            gTimeStringReduced.append(char)
            print("reduced: ", gTimeStringReduced)
        }
    }
//remove the colon from the end of the string
    for ch in gTimeStringReduced.dropLast() {
        print(ch)
        // `ch` is a Character. Use `String(ch)` if you need a String.
    }
```

I've also just realised the above code will always remove the final character whether its a colon or not, which also isn't much use!

All help appreciated!

Comment: If it's `00:25:00:30` you still want the same result? Or only double `00` which are at the start/end (ie, a trim) ?

Comment: ah no if its 00:25:00:30 I'd want 25:00:30

Comment: If you are going to remove both prefix and suffix under certain circumstances how do you know that `01:30:10` is hh:mm:ss rather than mm:ss:ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have always `"00:"` to remove if it's at the start or `":00"` if it's at the end, let's think it that way:

While the string has "00:" at the beginning, we remove it.
While the string has ":00" at the end, we remove it.

In code:

```
func trimmingZeroTime(str: String) {
    var text = str
    print("Initial: \(text)")
    while text.hasPrefix("00:") {
        text = String(text.dropFirst(3))
    }
    while text.hasSuffix(":00") {
        text = String(text.dropLast(3))
    }
    print("final: \(text)")
}
```

Sample tests:

```
trimmingZeroTime(str: "00:25:30:00")
trimmingZeroTime(str: "00:25:00:30:00")
trimmingZeroTime(str: "00:00:25:00:30:00")
trimmingZeroTime(str: "00:00:25:00:00")
```

Output:

```
Initial: 00:25:30:00
final: 25:30
Initial: 00:25:00:30:00
final: 25:00:30
Initial: 00:00:25:00:30:00
final: 25:00:30
Initial: 00:00:25:00:00
final: 25
```

## **EDIT:**

As the author as specified its final use, I recommend to use [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/unitsstyle) instead of a manual parsing.

Comment: not sure if OP wants to drop more than one occurrence

Comment: Ok this looks good, I'm going to give it a try!

Comment: @LeoDabus Indeed, I made assumption. Also, "00:00:00:00" should result in empty string...

Comment: Even more simple-minded than mine! Proving once again that it's good enough just to say what you mean. :)

Comment: Specs definition, with question analogy is indeed an important part of coding, getting edges cases, explicit samples/unit tests, etc... I'll keep the answer as such until @Chris give more samples to know if my answer cover all cases or not. If not, I'll delete or update it.$

Comment: Perfect solution thank you all and specifically @Larme!

Comment: In this example `00:25:00:00` I aim to have the label display "25hrs" but I've already got an idea to work out which ":00" has been removed so I can add the unit to the end of the trimmed string

Comment: Are you looking for `DateComponentsFormatter` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/unitsstyle ?

Comment: Wow yes! I did not know this existed!

Comment: @Chris  check its [maximumunitcount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1416214-maximumunitcount) and [zeroformattingbehavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1413749-zeroformattingbehavior) properties